# Attaching a warning by text width

Tags: javascript, css, alert

I built a form using EAMILMEFORM platform, 
I changed some CSS thigs and now my form look like this ( after clicking on submit button, and the field are not fill correct) 
[image]

I want no space between the text box alert. An example of what I want is at the link below:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hpqb863dvc6nn6w/%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%93%D7%94%20%282%29.PNG
How can I do it? 
the form online: http://lawb.co.il/HTMLPage.html

the JS code: http://lawb.co.il/contact.js

Another JS code: http://lawb.co.il/contact_us.js

the CSS code: http://lawb.co.il/contact_us.css

Pleas help me with my quastion, Thank oy si much.

Comment: It's taking width from the large container and applying the same to all messages. Try commenting this code and make the width auto for all elements.

Answer (score 1):

remove `width: 240px !important;` from css of `.formError .formErrorContent` you will get the result

Comment: Thank you! I did it, and got this result   http://dropbox.com/s/hkf69alm7w3n2o2/2.PNG?m This Is good but they are not in one line, how can I set up the setting so the will be in one line? here is an example for waht I mean http://dropbox.com/s/dtotte6hvx19673/15-09-2012%2014-54-02.png can you help me with it pleas?

Comment: "float: הזכות" שימוש זה יעזור לך לצאת לזה

Comment: I will try.. How You know hebrew?

Comment: google translate dear :) we Indians welcome every language "Google לתרגם יקרים :) אנו מקבלים בברכה כל שפת אינדיאנים"

Comment: Oh OK you can write an English too Its ok, I try 'float:right' nothing change... why?

Comment: ya sure but wait for some time i am working for some code after that i will

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `width` property applied to the `.formError .formErrorContent` rule in *contact_us.css*:

```css
.formError .formErrorContent {
    width: 240px !important; /* <-- omit */
}
```

If you desire to deal with alignment as well, that's a little bit more tricky, as the library assign positioning rules as inline styles for each `.formError` element, e.g.:

```html
<div class="formError element_2formError" style="top: 214px; left: 482px;">
<!-----------------------------------------------------------^ injected -->
```

Comment: Thank you! I did it, and got this result https://www.dropbox.com/s/hkf69alm7w3n2o2/2.PNG?m
This Is good but they are not in one line, how can I set up the setting so the will be in one line? 
here is an example for waht I mean 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtotte6hvx19673/15-09-2012%2014-54-02.png
can you help me with it pleas?

Comment: refer to my answer, that is not possible within the scope of external CSS. if you really wish to customize every aspect of those messages, drop the use of this library and find one that's more customizable. otherwise, accept it as it is and don't mingle with it too much.

Comment: Thank you, I just saw you answer, I dont Understand waht you mean, can you pleas give me an example about the align part?

Comment: open the developer tools of your favorable browser, and see what i mean. there's only so much *other* people can do for you.